# sql - HAVING at least 10

Tags: sql

i would like to display results for values that are only 10 and over

```
select  name, count(*) from actor
join casting on casting.actorid = actor.id
where casting.ord = 1
group  by name
order by 2 desc
```

that will return this:

```
name    count(*)
Sean Connery    19
Harrison Ford   19
Robert De Niro  18
Sylvester Stallone  18
```

etc

but i want to return values of count(*) that are only above 10

how do i do this? with having?

Comment: sounds like you know the answer already - did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `having` clause for this.

```
select  name, count(*) from actor
join casting on casting.actorid = actor.id
where casting.ord = 1
group  by name
having count(*) > 10
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: My scoreboard shows a -ve vote for my answer? What's wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
HAVING COUNT(*)>10
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select  name, count(*) from actor
join casting on casting.actorid = actor.id
where casting.ord = 1
group  by name
having count(*)>10
order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  name, count(*) from actor
join casting on casting.actorid = actor.id
where casting.ord = 1
group  by name having count(*) > 10
order by 2 desc
```